# how can I upload large SQL DB files into myphpadmin? (Using MariaDB 10.3.7, Innodb, PHP 7.2 on the synology server)

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, innodb, synology, mariadb-10.3

I have been stucked with large sql file uploading into my phpmyadmin.

I'm using the synology DSM 6.2, wordpress, MariaDB 10.3.7-0051, PHP 7.2, innodb, apache http 2.4 server.

My exported sql file size is about 360M but whenever I upload the sql file by using SSH, it shows it's too large error.

I'v been searching for many sites, but I can't find the answer.

What I saw were

1. Make my.cnf file and write something...(But I don't know what it is)
2. Change some options maxallowed packet or, max log file size and so on. (Where should I change this options? my.cnf file? or somewhere in the phpmyadmin? or somewhere?)

What should I do to upload large SQL file into my database?

Please, let me know how I can clear this issue.
(where should I go to change options, how can I command and what command I must write... Because I'm ROOKIE for using the SQL)

Thanks.

Comment: `max_allowed_packet`.

Comment: max_allowed_packet ? Which file should I put this file? Please, let me know the details. Thanks.

Comment: Search for `mariadb max_allowed_packet`.  It needs to go into the `[mysqld]` section of `my.cnf`.  Alas, I don't know where that config file is on your system.  Set it to `500M`, and restart mariadb.

Comment: Also, if searching with `mariadb` does not give enough satisfaction, search with `mysql`; in many situations, the information will be more plentiful and still valid.

Comment: Hello, Rick. Even I add and changed the "max allowed packet", but it still shows this error. "ERROR 1118 (42000) at line 841: Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 0 bytes is stored inline."